# How to pass a Map<Key,Object> to a ListView in Wicket?

Tags: jakarta-ee, wicket

I have the following Map:

```
Map<Integer, Object> mapCompetencies = new TreeMap<Integer, Object>();
```

I want to pass it to the `ListView`!!

I used `LoadableDetachableModel` as the following but it replicates the data for all items.

```
    IModel<List<Map.Entry<Integer, Object>>> mapModel = new LoadableDetachableModel<List<Entry<Integer, Object>>>() {
        @Override
        protected List<Entry<Integer, Object>> load() {
            return new ArrayList<Map.Entry<Integer,Object>>(mapCompetencies.entrySet());
        }
    };
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? This sounds suspiciously like a design issue.

Comment: Thank for the reply, I want to use both the key and the value of `Map` in the items of the list. Actually, I solved the problem by creating a class with `key` and `value` attributes and created a `List` of that class instead of the `Map`. Now it works but I would prefer using `Map` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you do something like this for the listView?

```
LoadableDetachableModel<Map<Integer,Object>> model = new LoadableDetachableModel<Map<Integer,Object>>() {

            @Override
            protected Map<Integer, Object> load() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return mapCompetencies;
            }
        };

    ListView lv = new ListView("id",new ArrayList<Integer>(model.getObject().keySet())){
        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem<Integer> item) {
        //do something here
        //to take the object , you could just do
        Object o = model.getObject().get(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @RobAu , thanks for the edit , I did not notice that missing "()".